# Meteor - How to create a custom field validation for a form

Tags: meteor

I want to create a custom field validation for forms using Meteor. I don't want a packaged solution.

Here is my code so far.

JavaScript:

```
var errorState = new ReactiveVar;


Template.lottoForm.created = function() {
    errorState.set('errors', {});
};


Template.lottoForm.events({
    'blur input': function(e, t) {
        e.preventDefault();
        validate($(this));
    }
});


Template.lottoForm.helpers({
    errorClass: function (key) {
        return errorState.get('errors')[key] ? 'has-error' : '';
    }
});


Template.errorMsg.helpers({
    errorMessages: function(key) {
        return errorState.get('errors');
    }
});

function throwError(message) {
    errorState.set('errors', message)
    return errorState.get('errors');
}


function validate(formField) {
    $("input").each(function(index, element){
        var fieldValue = $(element).val();
        if(fieldValue){
            if(isNaN(fieldValue) == true) {
                throwError('Not a valid Number');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<template name="lottoForm">
    <form class="playslip form-inline" role="form">
      <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group {{errorClass 'ball0'}}">
          <input type="text" class="input-block form-control" id="ball0" maxlength="2" name="ball0">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group {{errorClass 'ball1'}}">
          <input type="text" class="input-block form-control" id="ball1" maxlength="2" name="ball1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group {{errorClass 'ball2'}}">
          <input type="text" class="input-block form-control" id="ball2" maxlength="2" name="ball2">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group {{errorClass 'ball3'}}">
          <input type="text" class="input-block form-control" id="ball3" maxlength="2" name="ball3">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group {{errorClass 'ball4'}}">
          <input type="text" class="input-block form-control" id="ball4" maxlength="2" name="ball4">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group {{errorClass 'ball5'}}">
          <input type="text" class="input-block form-control" id="ball5" maxlength="2" name="ball5">
        </div>
        {{> errorMsg}}
        <div class="play-btn">
          <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Play Syndicate</button>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
</template

<template name="errorMsg">
    <div class="errorMsg">
      {{#if errorMessages}}
          <div class="list-errors">
            {{#each errorMessages}}
                <div class="list-item">{{> fieldError}}</div>
            {{/each}}
          </div>
      {{/if}}
    </div>
</template>

<template name="fieldError">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
      {{errors}}
    </div>
</template>
```

I'm also getting this error message in the console - "Uncaught Error: {{#each}} currently only accepts arrays, cursors or falsey values."

Why do I get this error and how would I implement the custom validation?

Answer (score 0):

Just as the error says, #each template functions must be passed the proper type. Are you sure your errorMessages helper is returning an array? It looks like you are initializing it as a hash.

Comment: Thanks Jason, the error msg has gone but nothing else works. Any ideas?

Comment: I referenced the key like so: return errorState.get('errors')[key] which got rid of the error msg.

Comment: Jason any ideas how I can get the rest of it working?

Comment: Is your code up to date in your question? Please also post the entire console log from your browser. It depends on what line the error is occurring.

Comment: Jason, my console is clean as whistle. no errors showing up at all but yet nothing is working.

Comment: And you are sure that your errorMessages helper is returning an array? You still have  errorState.set('errors', {}); << this is not an array

Comment: Post your full code as a project on Github; make it private if need be. My username is appjitsu. It's hard to see what the problem is unless I'm able to run it.

Comment: Hi Jason, the project is  on GH...my username: gussandy